# RequestLogger 'contains' method expected behavior

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, devexpress, end-to-end, testcafe

Working on an end-to-end test suite with the TestCafe framework.

I'm trying to implement assertions on requests URL parameters, and requests firing/not firing depending on frontend use cases.

The kind of components under test are a table Filter panel with a lot of filters.

So i test each filter one by one and make assertions on the requests parameters formats depending on each filter type.

In the end i'd like to check that when clearing filters there is no request firing with any of the filters parameters.

In my understanding, if I do not call the "clear" method of the logger before doing this last assertion, this should not pass. But the test is actually green.

It seems to me like I'm not correctly understanding the behavior of the logger. contains assertion mechanism? Does it always check the latest request only? Or does it check against any of the logged requests?

Here is my test code :

```
test('Transactions Base Filters', async (t) => {
  // amount filter
  await t.typeText(filters.grossAmountMin, '10')
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(1)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('grossAmount=10__value') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .typeText(filters.grossAmountMax, '5')
    .expect(filters.grossAmountMin.getReact(({ props: { error } }) => error)).ok()
    .expect(filters.grossAmountMax.getReact(({ props: { error } }) => error)).ok()
    // check invalid input does not fire a request
    .expect(logger.count(r => r.request.url.indexOf('grossAmount=10__value__5') > 0)).eql(0)
    .typeText(filters.grossAmountMax, '00')
    .expect(filters.grossAmountMin.getReact(({ props: { error } }) => error)).notOk()
    .expect(filters.grossAmountMax.getReact(({ props: { error } }) => error)).notOk()
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('grossAmount=10__value__500') > 0
    ))).ok();

  // orderId filter
  await t.typeText(filters.orderId, '8E')
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(2)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('orderId=*8E*') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .click(filters.orderId)
    .pressKey('ctrl+a delete')
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(1);

  // email filter
  await t.typeText(filters.customerEmail, 'fvrecord')
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(2)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('customerEmail=*fvrecord*') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .click(filters.customerEmail)
    .pressKey('ctrl+a delete')
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(1);

  // status filter
  await t.click(filters.status)
    .click(filters.statusMenuItem('VALIDATED'))
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(2)
    .expect(filters.status.getReact(({ props: { value } }) => value.length)).eql(1)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('status=VALIDATED') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .click(filters.status)
    .click(filters.statusMenuItem('REFUSED'))
    .expect(filters.status.getReact(({ props: { value } }) => value.length)).eql(2)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('status=VALIDATED|REFUSED') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .click(filters.status)
    .click(filters.statusMenuItem('VALIDATED'))
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('status=VALIDATED') > 0
    ))).ok()
    .click(filters.status)
    .click(filters.statusMenuItem('REFUSED'))
    .expect(filters.status.getReact(({ props: { value } }) => value.length)).eql(0)
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(1);

  // transactionType filter
  await t.click(filters.type)
    .click(filters.statusMenuItem('DEBIT'))
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(2)
    .expect(filters.type.getReact(({ props: { value } }) => value.length)).eql(1)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('type=DEBIT') > 0
    ))).ok();

  // reset all
  // logger.clear();
  await t.click(filters.resetButton)
    .expect(filters.activeFilter.count).eql(0)
    .expect(logger.contains(r => (
      r.response.statusCode === 200
      && r.request.url.indexOf('grossAmount=') < 0
      && r.request.url.indexOf('orderId=') < 0
      && r.request.url.indexOf('customerEmail=') < 0
      && r.request.url.indexOf('status=') < 0
      && r.request.url.indexOf('type=') < 0
    ))).ok();
});
```

Comment: We are going to fix this issue in the context of the following thread: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2688

Comment: @Marion Thank you for looking at my issue.
This thread is not a duplicate of the issue as it is more about understanding the **expected behavior of the RequestLogger.contains method**.

Comment: 1. The contains(predicate) method works as described in the following help topic: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html#logger-methods. 
It returns whether the logger contains a request that matches the predicate. In other words, it returns true/false based on whether there is at least one request that meets the predicate.

Comment: 2. It looks like there is misunderstanding the in the following scenario: "In the end i'd like to check that when clearing filters there is no request firing with any of the filters parameters". From what I gather, you wish to be ensure that a request with filter parameters is not sent after you clear the filter. Yet according to your code, you check if a request is sent, but without parameters.

Comment: 3. Please send me your URL to which the request is sent after resetting the resetAll button so that we can check whether or not the request is defined correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It confirms the expected behavior of the contains method. For my testing scenario, there is a request firing after resetting all filters, and i want to check that there is no filter parameters in this final request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that there are no filter parameters in this final request using logger and Node.js modules ([url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost), [querystirng](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)). For example:

```
.expect(logger.contains (r => r.response.statusCode == 200 && checkParameters(r.request.url)))

function checkParameters(url) {
   var parsedUrl = url.parse(url):
   var parsedParameters = querystring.parse(url.path);

return parsedParameters.param1 === '' && parsedParamters.param2 == '' ...
```

}